# MariaDB Show Columns Privileges

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a user who needs to be able to call `SHOW COLUMNS FROM <db.table>;` on a MariaDB database.  What privilege do I need to grant the user to do this as I am getting `ER_TABLEACCESS_DENIED_ERROR` at the moment?

The user already has the following permissions on the db in question:
`CREATE, SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, EXECUTE, GRANT OPTION, DROP, CREATE VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, SHOW VIEW, REFERENCES, SHOW DATABASES`

Thanks

Comment: It depends on what databases and tables the user has these rights on, obviously. Unfortunately you haven't mentioned it.

Comment: @fancyPants All the permissions above are on the database which contains the table in question.

The user was granted the permissions using `GRANT CREATE, SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, EXECUTE, GRANT OPTION, DROP, CREATE VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, SHOW VIEW, REFERENCES, SHOW DATABASES ON *.* TO <username>;`

Comment: SHOW COLUMNS displays information about the columns in a given table. It also works for views. SHOW COLUMNS displays information only for those columns for which you have some privilege... SELECT privilege should be needed for this command to work.... try to use  FLUSH PRIVILEGES maybe that helps

Comment: Thanks @RaymondNijland - that sorted it :)

Comment: Ok i will add mine comment as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> SHOW COLUMNS displays information about the columns in a given table.
>   It also works for views. SHOW COLUMNS displays information only for
>   those columns for which you have some privilege

SELECT privilege should be needed for this command to work.

Use FLUSH PRIVILEGES to reload the PRIVILEGES for the user